# css3 Transition transform let white space between elements

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have an animation bewteen 2 div. Idealy, I want the to "push" each other so it FEELS like it's a 3d box rotating on Z.

I have this

```css
body {
  overflow:hidden
}

div {
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
}

div:first-child {
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#453525;
  transform:scaleX(1);
  transition:transform .8s ease-out, width .8s ease-in, left .8s ease-in;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  left:101%;
  width:0;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#754512;
  transform:scaleX(0);
  transition:transform .8s ease-out, width .8s ease-in, left .8s ease-in;
}

body:hover div:first-child {
  transform:scaleX(0);
  width:0;
  left:-101%;
}

body:hover div:nth-child(2) {
  transform:scaleX(1); 
  width:100%;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there's a huge space inbetween my divs. I tried to lower the transition duration of the first div so the second one get close, but no matter what I still got a white space.

[Here is a fiddle to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/cf85sdrt/)

Any idea?

EDIT: The divs in my project contains stuff, so when it scales up or down that looks like it's turning, that's why I don't use a simple width or left transition alone

Comment: The fiddle you provided looks really weird and what you want to do seems unclear to me, could you explain a bit more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get rid of the left transtion and adjust the transform origin so that both div stay linked:

```css
body {
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}

div {
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
}

div:first-child {
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#453525;
  transform:scaleX(1);
  transform-origin:right;
  transition:transform .8s ease-out, width .8s ease-in;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  right:0;
  width:0;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#754512;
  transform:scaleX(0);
  transform-origin:left;
  transition:transform .8s ease-out, width .8s ease-in;
}

body:hover div:first-child {
  transform:scaleX(0);
  width:0;
}

body:hover div:nth-child(2) {
  transform:scaleX(1); 
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea. I did your solution, I added a wrapper around my div and animate its left position to get the perfect result :) Thank you!